# Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0

Tags: android, zxing

Android Studio 3.0.1, Gradle 4.1

I want to generate QR in my android app.
so I try to use: **com.google.zxing**

in project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$REALM_VERSION"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in  **app/bulld.gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

But I get error:

Error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0.

Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0 available for offline mode.
```

Comment: Try to **clean** and **rebuild** project.

Comment: I try, but it not help

Comment: Is your network connection is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can download ZXing `core.jar` file for android from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/android-core/3.2.0/android-core-3.2.0.jar), put that file into  your project's libs folder.

Ensure that compile files('libs/android-core-3.2.0.jar') is in your build.gradle file (or compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') if you are using many jar files)